# Does the proof that "a proper ascending chain of subsets of the naturals is countable" necessitate axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $(A_x)_{x\in X}$ be a collection of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Using the Axiom of Choice, i.e. assuming there exists a function $f:\{A_x\}_{x\in X}\to \bigcup_{x\in X} A_x$, with $f(A_x)\in A_x$ for all $x\in X$, it follows by disjointness that this collection injects into $\mathbb{N}$.

My question is this: Are there proofs of this result that are not reliant on choice? Maybe DC? P.S. this is not my area of expertise :P Thanks!!

Comment: You have a well order on $\mathbb{N}$, so you can just choose the least element of $A_x$.

Comment: oh very true thanks

Comment: I just want to comment that the claim in the title is wrong. There exists uncountable ascending chains of subsets of the naturals. Dedekind cuts.

Comment: See for example the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3999062/11619). An expert on set theory may be able to point you at better explanations - I could only find my old related answer (so not voting to close as a duplicate). The point is that even though the sets $A_x$ are disjoint, you cannot necessarily find an **injective** function $f$ with the prescribed properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and sorry for the late response. I am just now seeing your comment about uncountable ascending chains in $\mathbb N$, and I see the motivation via Dedekind cuts. Still, what confuses me is the following, which I think led me to the reasoning that I followed to jump from the title to the body question: If I have an uncountable chain, at each index $i\in I$, I can try to construct a "derivative" at $i$, $D_i$. If I had a successor function $s$ on $X$ my indexing set, this would be simply $A_{s(i)}-A_{i}$. Without that, I might try to take a liminf...

Comment: Maybe not quite a liminf, but I might try $D_i:=\bigcup_{k>i}\bigcap_{j:i<j\leq k} \{a\in \mathbb N| a\in A_j-A_i\}$. If $D_i$ were empty, then any element $a\in A_j-A_i$ for $j>i$ would need to not be in $A_{j'}$ for some $i<j'\leq j$. But this would contradict monotonicity and our proper ascending condition (perhaps I'm being careless by assuming what seems intuitive about what a proper ascending chain of uncountable index means). But if that holds, it seems that the $(D_i)_{i\in X}$ should be disjoint, and thus the result follows from what the other commenter pointed out.